# How can I convert Stream<Byte> to InputStream

Tags: java, kotlin, stream, java-stream

I have `java.util.stream.Stream<Byte>` in Java/Kotlin(jvm).

How can I convert `java.util.stream.Stream<Byte>` to `java.io.InputStream` without keeping each buffer in memory.

I can do this conversion by

```
fun convertToInputStream(byteStream: Stream<Byte>) = ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream.collect(Collectors.toList()).toByteArray())
```

In my example I will get an OutOfMemoryError if I use a large limit because it creates a large byte[] in memory

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.File
import java.util.stream.Collectors
import java.util.stream.IntStream
import java.util.stream.Stream

fun convertToInputStream(byteStream: Stream<Byte>) = ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream.collect(Collectors.toList()).toByteArray())


fun main() {

    val file = File("/tmp/data.txt")
    val inputStream = convertToInputStream(
        IntStream.iterate(1) { 65 + it % 3 }.limit(1000000000).mapToObj { it.toByte() }
    )
    inputStream.copyTo(file.outputStream())
}
```

Comment: Why do we close this question?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The question seems clear enough to me. How would any further code improve it?

Comment: You already got a good answer, but it should be noted that a `Stream<Byte>` is **very** inefficient compared to an `InputStream`, since it requires multiple method calls for each byte transferred and some auto-boxing/auto-unboxing steps. So if you *can*, you should avoid reaching that abstraction level, especially if you're planning to handle non-trivial amounts of data.

Comment: I know it is very slow, but if you receive bytes from a slow channel and the channel is opened for a long time it can be a good solution because if you need some other stream functions like map, flatmap, filter you cannot do it with InputStream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement it with something like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val stream = Stream.of<Byte>(10, 15, -50, 20, 50)

    val buf = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    stream.asInputStream().transferTo(buf)

    val bytes = buf.toByteArray() // [10, 15, -50, 20, 50]
}

fun Stream<Byte>.asInputStream() = object : InputStream() {
    private val iter = iterator()

    override fun read() = if (iter.hasNext()) iter.next().toUByte().toInt() else -1
}
```

You would probably need to override more methods to improve performance or provide more functionality, like for example closing the stream.

Also, note that I didn't test this code thoroughly.

Comment: Why implement `read(b: ByteArray, off: Int, len: Int)` at all? How is the default implementation inefficient? Or put another way, in what way is your implementation better than the default implementation?

Comment: Hmm, you are right. In that case it doesn't make sense to override this method as we can only take one item at a time anyway. Thanks, I'll remove it.